# Get single value from array that is posted to php file

Tags: php, arrays, post, mailchimp

I am using mailchimp's webhook feature to (eventually) run a script on my app that will mark a user as unsubscribed from the newsletter if they unsubscribe through mailchimp.

Mailchimp is passing the following array to my script using POST.

```
Array
(
    [type] => unsubscribe
    [fired_at] => 2014-01-12 12:56:23
    [data] => Array
        (
            [action] => unsub
            [reason] => manual
            [id] => 1b3a2f11af
            [email] => email@domain.com
            [email_type] => html
            [ip_opt] => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
            [web_id] => 128403001
            [merges] => Array
                (
                    [EMAIL] => email@domain.com
                    [FNAME] => FNAME
                    [LNAME] => LNAME
                )

            [list_id] => 5c30250cdb
        )

)
```

My issue is, how can I get the [email] value out of it so that I can then pass that as a variable to update the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$email = $_POST ['data']['email'];

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$result_array = $_POST;
echo $result_array["data"]["email"]; // or $_POST["data"]["email"];
```